# PHP/MySQL keeping track of uses

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update my tables with a total number of uses when a function is called. What I need to do is grab the former number of uses, and add one. I have a pretty good general idea how to go about this, but I don't quite know how to get unique ID's with their respective uses. This is what I have so far...

```
<?php
 $query = $conn->query('select name, uses from users');
    $i = 0;
    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $name[$i] = $r->name;
        $uses[$i] = $r->uses;
    $i = $i+1;
    }
if(isset($_POST['mName']))
{
    $mName = urldecode($_POST['mName']);
    $mUses = $uses + 1;

"UPDATE users 
                        SET uses=:uses WHERE name=:name";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUPDATE);
$stmt->bindParam(':uses', $mUses);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $mName);
$stmt->execute();
 ?>
```

I can see my issue is that I'm assigning the uses variable to an array, I don't know how to get it specific to the username. Is this a simple SQL query I'm missing?

Comment: What is name, the name of the function or the name of the user? Are there any other columns in the table? Does the table have a unique key?

Comment: The name of the user, the table has a primary ID key, and also it has emails and times accessed

Comment: Why are you storing data in 2 arrays? Why not store it in 1. `$users[$i] = array('name' => $r->name, 'uses' => $r->uses);` Or instead of using the counter for the key, use the name of the user `$users[$r->name] = $r->uses;`

Comment: I don't know much SQL so I've been reusing a lot of my code, the arrays were usually set for output lists. $users[$r->name] = $r->uses; looks like something I tried to get to work earlier! So how would I go about updating the uses with this format? if $users(name==$name){SET uses=:uses WHERE name=:name";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUPDATE);
$stmt->bindParam(':uses', $mUses);}? Sorry, again, I'm not very tailored in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data in an array called `$uses` with the key being the user name and the value being the number of uses. Then if you detect a POST with the mName parameter set, you can reference your `$uses` array with that name and get the number of uses, and add 1.

```
<?php
    $query = $conn->query('select name, uses from users');
    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $uses[$r->name] = $r->uses;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['mName'])) {
        $mName = urldecode($_POST['mName']);
        $mUses = $uses[$mName] + 1;
        $sqlUPDATE = "UPDATE users SET uses=:uses WHERE name=:name";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUPDATE);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uses', $mUses);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $mName);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
?>
```

Though there is no error checking and handling in here. If there happens to be a POST with mName and that name doesn't exist, nothing will update, but nothing will insert for new users. Also, instead of using a name, it would be better to use an id for the user if possible.

Comment: while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $uses[$i] = $r->uses;
    }

Does [$I] need a declaration, or is it automatically filled in from the query?

Edit: I just ran it, it didn't work :|

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change `$i` to `$r->name`

Comment: Okay I figured lol, I changed it and it worked. Thank you so much! :)